Manhwa where the female lead is a chef and a hidden princess
The female lead (FL) of the manhwa was a princess that was hidden from the public in an abandoned palace. I think she got reincarnated into the manhwa and knew the story's plot, since she made dishes from the modern world. She knew she was going to die early on in the story so her only goal was to eat a really good meal or something like that before she died.
She and her royal family were captured by the male lead (ML) and his superior and she was supposed to be executed alongside them, but she pulled out this jerky cheese stick thingy and started snacking on it instead of being scared or bothered. She offered it to the ML and he let them live a little longer, because he had a curse which made all food taste awful to him, but hers tasted good and he thought she was a witch so he captured her. Fastforward, he makes her his private chef and kinda falls in love with her.
The FL finally proves her worth to her family over her food, only for them to be executed, besides her sister, who the ML's superior wants to marry, but she refuses, almost starving herself to death until the FL comforts her with food and gives her a little advice.

Is this Savor the Taste...?

Luana is reborn as an illegitimate princess inside a book. Resigned to her fate, she decides to spend her days cooking. Not long after, the cursed Duke Legion arrives and sacks the kingdom, but instead of falling for the princess, he's bewitched by Luana's food. He orders her to cook for him or die!


The female lead is reincarnated within a romantic fantasy novel as Luana, the sixth princess of a kingdom. In the novel, Luana was a minor character who was kept hidden away in an abandoned castle due to being the illegitimate daughter of the King and a lowly handmaiden. She made the most of her lonely life by cooking and eating delicious food.
The original male lead of the novel was a warmongering emperor who planned to conquer the entire continent. When he saw the original female lead of the novel, Ingrid, the first princess of the Kingdom, he asked her to be his concubine but she refused, which infuriated him, so he ordered his subordinate, Duke Legion, to seize the Kingdom.
In the first chapter, Luana is captured by the Duke's soldiers and brought before him, alongside the other royals of the Kingdom, who barely know her. The Duke notices Luana fidgeting with something so he has her searched by his soldiers, who find a stick of beef jerky with cheese on her. He takes a bite out of it and then has her thrown in a prison cell.
Later, the Duke visits Luana and accuses her of being a witch, since he liked the beefy jerky she made, despite the fact that a witch had placed a curse on his family that made any food they ate taste foul.
You can read the full manhwa at Manta.
